# Creating the navigation/flow of a MAUI application

Tags: xamarin, navigation, maui

My application is fairly simple, but I'm having issues with how best to setup the navigation/flow of my app using Shell and whether it's best to use Current.GoToAsync() or Current.Navigation.PushAsync() to go between the pages. (Or if there's a better way.)

My app starts off with a splash page, then to a login page, then to a tabbed page with 2 options. Each of those tabs show pages with list views where clicking on one of the items takes you to a detail page with a back button to go back to the list view page.

There's also a settings button in the header of the tabbed page that will display a flyout page of settings.

[This crude drawing kinda shows what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDCWk.png)

Currently, in AppShell.xaml I have:

```
<Shell>
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SplashScreen}" />
</Shell>
```

After the user logs in they're taken to MainPage.xaml which is a TabbedPage setup like so:

```
<TabbedPage>
    <views:DemoPageA Title="A" />
    <views:DemoPageB Title="B" />
</TabbedPage>
```

Unfortunately, I'm always seeing a back button on every screen. I don't want users to go back to the splash screen or login screen, for example.

I'm just not sure if I need to somehow define my app differently in AppShell.xaml.cs or what. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why mixing Shell with TabbedPage since Shell supports Tabs too ? also it is a waste if you are using Shell only for one page. Please narrow your question (on back button issue?) and include more details how you are navigating from Shell to TabbedPage.

Comment: @Cfun That's what I'm getting at: How can I make a Shell that represents the flow/navigation of the app I want to build? Regular page, regular page, tabbed page with list view pages that navigate to regular pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code to your page to hide the back button in the shell:

```
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
   <BackButtonBehavior IsEnabled="False" IsVisible="False"/>
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
```

Here is related article about it: [Back button behavior| Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#back-button-behavior)